# How to call a dynamic Rspec matcher should or should_not

Tags: ruby, rspec

```
def some_method condition
  actual = [1,2,3]
  expected = include(1)
  matcher = lambda {|condition|
            if condition == "YES"
              return RSpec::Matcher.should
            else
              return RSpec::Matcher.should_not
            end}
  actual.matcher.call(condition) expected
end
```

How to dynamically make a should or should_not matcher based on condition parsed into the method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you meant to do is:

```
def some_method condition
  actual = [1,2,3]
  expected = include(1)
  matcher = lambda {|condition|
            if condition == "YES"
              :should
            else
              :should_not
            end}
  actual.send(&matcher.call(condition), expected)
end
```

This will either call the method `should` or `should_not` on the actual result.

On a side note, I'm having quite a difficulty seeing when this would be a good idea... Unit tests should be deterministic and readable, and this idea makes them less of both...

Comment: Thank you very much. I agree with you that it should not be used, I was just curious how to do it. When I was just trying to do `actual.send(matcher.call(condition), expected)` it didn't work. Now I see why. Thank you very much for your help. I appreciate it. (Use case was in Cucumber step definition to pass "SHOULD" or "SHOULD_NOT" for the same step and handle it.